# how to get and set the value in a java program

Tags: java

i want the code of how to get and set the values of a field in a java program

Comment: the best question yet! ;-) no offence, this really made my day :-)

Comment: @Peter: did you like it so much you actually **upvoted** it?

Comment: The statement "get and set values of a field in a java program" is a bit broad.  Do you want to get and set values of a field of corn?  Perhaps a field on a web page?  Maybe a field (also known as a property) in an object?  Do you want to get and set values in your field of vision?  Some of these are easy to answer, others are more difficult.

Comment: This question gets the dubious honor as the first question I voted to close. :)

Comment: Do you want do it using reflection?

Comment: i want world domination - none of us will get what he wants with such a unspecific, short command and without trying to do it ourselves (and _ask for help_ if we have problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to see code like this?

```
public class Foo
{
   int bar;
   public void setBar(int newbar)
   {
     bar=newbar;
   }
   public int getBar()
   {
     return bar;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to check out the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  The ones on [Language Basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), and [Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) will be a good place to start.  They have examples that show what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
this.x = x
```

and

```
return this.x
```